# jQuery keyup, is there a keyleave or similar?

Tags: jquery, keyup

How to detect when the user leave (or unfocus) a text field using the tab key?
I can't find a keyleave event.

Youssef

Comment: Are you looking for the [Blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the event you are looking for is [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) .

The [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) describes this event as follows:

> The blur event is fired when an element has lost focus. The main difference between this event and focusout is that only the latter bubbles.

This is not exclusive to the the tab key - even clicking outside of the element will trigger the blur event.

You use it in the same way as you would for any other jquery event:

```
$( element ).on( "blur", function() {
  // element has lost focus
} );

// Or

$( element ).blur( function() {
  // element has lost focus
} );
```

Comment: @user2668652 - Happy to help! :) If you feel that this answer helped you out you can consider marking it as the ["accepted answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). this is the best way to indicate to future visitors which answer you felt helped you the most. You are not required to do this at all, but "accepting" and "voting" is the best way to say thank you on [so] :)